# Date format on chart from unix

Tags: unix, date, highcharts

Have put together a simple chart in Highcharts which is compiling from data supplied:

```
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                fill: 'none',
                stroke: 'none',
                style: {
                    color: '#039',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fill: 'white'
                    },
                    select: {
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            inputStyle: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                color: 'silver',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Data',
            data: [
[1325376000,102.2],
[1328054400,104.5],
[1330560000,106.7],
[1333238400,109.8],
[1335830400,122.1],
[1338508800,124.3],
]
        }]
    });
});
```

However, the date data (e.g. 1325376000) renders simply as hours on the x-axis on the chart and the dates show in the top appear as 1970... can you tell me where I have gone wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts expects its dates in milliseconds. I think you are supplying seconds?

Comment: I converted the dates using a website. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/bGBpg/

Comment: That jsfiddle doesn't work for me. The date numbers still look to small. Try multiplying them by 1000 to convert to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You have i.e 1325376000 which is timestamp, (date in 1970). Do you use UNIX timestamps or other? Which date should be? You can use i.e Date.UTC() to prepare appropaite date http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp

Comment: Well I can see how to use the Date.UTC but how would I do it using a timestamp as above and show the date (e.g. 23 March) only not the time...

Comment: You can use highcharts.dateFormat() in label's formatter 
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#highcharts.dateFormat()

Comment: highcharts.dateFormat() doesn't bring up anything in the API reference even if it recognises the string...

Comment: dateFormat() based on number, to transform string to number you can use parseFloat();

Comment: So, what is the code I use? e.g. series: [{
            name: 'Data',
            data: [
[dateFormat(1325376000),102.2],
[dateFormat(1328054400),104.5],
[dateFormat(1330560000),106.7],
[dateFormat(1333238400),109.8],
[dateFormat(1335830400),122.1],
[dateFormat(1338508800),124.3],
]
        }]

Comment: First of all if you use pointStart then you should use also timestamp, insetad of year. Secondly you should multiply your unix timestamps by 1000 and you will achive correct dates. http://jsfiddle.net/bGBpg/1/

Comment: Great - thank you. Just starting out with this. Could you take a look at my other post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418947/using-data-or-csv-to-create-charts-in-highstock